# Add array elements between each of the existing array elements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, phpexcel

I am trying to create a report in Excel by fetching data from MySql. I need to get subject headings from the database and output them to the excel sheet as columns e.g cell: D5, E5, F5 ... M5 etc.

So far I have managed to do so, therefore the display under the cells holds headings something like:

D5:Mathematics, E5:English, F5:Physics, etc.

```
  | A | B | C | D           | E       | F       | G   | H   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1 |   |   |   |             |         |         |     |     |
...
5 |   |   |   | Mathematics | English | Physics | ... | ... |
```

which is fine. The challenge is, I need to insert a `GRADE` heading in between each of the `Subject`s, something like this:

```
  | A | B | C | D           | E     | F       | G     | H       | I     | J   | K   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |   |   |   |             |       |         |       |         |       |     |     |
...
5 |   |   |   | Mathematics | GRADE | English | GRADE | Physics | GRADE | ... | ... |
```

Now here is what I have so far:

```
$stringindex = "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // For the excel column cells
$arr_index = str_split($stringindex); // create array elements
$arr_val2 = array(); // create array
$subject = array();
$subname2 = array();


while($sub_row = mysqli_fetch_array($resub, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $subject[] = $sub_row['name']; // Get the subjects from the database and put them in an array
}

foreach($subject as $sub => $subname) {
    $subkey[] = $sub; // array of subject keys e.g 0|1|2|3
    $subname2[] = $subname; // array of subjects
}

foreach($arr_index as $arr => $arr_val) {
    $arr_val2[] = $arr_val; // array of letters e.g D|E|F|G
}

$acount = count($subname2);
$bcount = count($arr_val2);

$size = ($acount > $bcount) ? $bcount : $acount;
$a = array_slice($subname2, 0, $size);
$b = array_slice($arr_val2, 0, $size);

$combine = array_combine($a, $b);

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); // PHPExcel functions

foreach($combine as $key => $val) { // GET SUBJECTS
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($val)->setAutoSize(true); // Sets Column Width

     $sheet
        ->setCellValue($val.'5', $key); // Lists Subjects as columns

} // END of FOREACH LOOP
```

The above code is able to display the subjects as column headings in excel:

QUESTION:
How do I add a code to add a GRADE column after each subject heading?

I hope you'll point me in the right direction coz' I am now stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're going to have one row per student, what will you be putting in each of the 'subject' columns if not the grade?

Comment: @Squig, yes it is one row per student and under each subject I display percentage mark e.g 95 and then under GRADE I display A

Comment: And presumably, you want to keep them in separate columns (rather than having something like `95% (A)` in a single column) in order to perform some calculations on the percentages (such as high, low, mean, median...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$stringindex = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";    // For the excel column cells
$columns = str_split($stringindex);             // create array elements
$rowIndex = 5;      // start at row 5 in Excel
$columnIndex = 3;   // start at column D in Excel
$subjects = array();

while($sub_row = mysqli_fetch_array($resub, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $subject[] = $sub_row['name']; // Get the subjects from the database and put them in an array
}

$sheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); // PHPExcel functions
foreach($subject as $index => $subjectName) { // GET SUBJECTS
    $columnName = getColumnName($columnIndex, $columns);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnName)->setAutoSize(true); // Sets Column Width
    $sheet->setCellValue($columnName.$rowIndex, $subjectName); // Lists Subjects as columns
    $columnIndex++;

    $columnName = getColumnName($columnIndex, $columns);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnName)->setAutoSize(true); // Sets Column Width
    $sheet->setCellValue($columnName.$rowIndex, "GRADE"); 
    $columnIndex++;
} // END of FOREACH LOOP

function getColumnName($index, $columns) {
    $columnName = "";
    $numColumns = count($columns);
    while($index >= $numColumns) {
        $columnName = $columns[($index % $numColumns)] . $columnName;
        $index = floor($index / $numColumns) - 1;
    }
    $columnName = $columns[($index % $numColumns)] . $columnName;
    return $columnName;
}
```

I added a function *getColumnName()* which gives you "AA", "AB", ... in the event that your subject and grade columns go past the A-Z limit.

Comment: u know what? your code seems to solve my problem...preliminary tests show it has potential in what i'm trying to achieve...lemme test it alittle more then i'll give this a thumbs up.

Comment: after putting the code in the pan and adding more ingredients, it has worked for me, so again, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I consider this problem solved.

Comment: You can, of course, replace all that getColumnName() stuff with PHPExcel's built-in PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex() method; or just take advantage of PHP's character incrementor( $columnName='A'; $columnName++;)

Answer (score 0):

$temp=true;

then in the loop that goes through columns:

```
if($temp==true){
    //do stuff
    $temp=false;
}else{
    //do other stuff
    $temp=true;
}
```